# FNV-1A hash - xoring 4 bytes at a time

Tags: algorithm, hash

Are there any adverse effects if during calculation of [FNV-1a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) hash, 4 bytes are xor'ed at a time rather than just one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a problem. The algorithm does an XOR on each byte and then multiplies to "mix" that byte with the rest of the value. If you did an XOR on four bytes at a time, the last four bytes of the value you're hashing would have an overwhelming effect on the result.

Basically, the calculation was designed to mix in one byte at a time. If you mix in four bytes at a time, you'll change the distribution of the values that it produces.